# Django forms.Form widgets and Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: django, forms, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to integrate Jquery UI's Autocomplete but I am not having any luck. I have been successful in implementing datepicker so i decided to use the same approach.

form.py

```
from django import forms
from asset_db.models import Profiles


class SubmitJob(forms.Form):

    material_id = forms.CharField(max_length=8, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'autocomplete'}))
    workflow = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profiles.objects.distinct('name'), to_field_name='name')
    start_datepicker = forms.CharField(max_length=12, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
    end_datepicker = forms.CharField(max_length=12, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
```

submit.html

```
{% extends 'website/header.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p><b>Submit Job</b></p>
    <form action="{% url 'job' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker();
            });
        </script>
        <script>
          $( function() {
            var availableTags = [
              "ActionScript",
              "AppleScript",
              "Asp",
              "BASIC",
              "C",
              "C++",
              "Clojure",
              "COBOL",
              "ColdFusion",
            ];
            $( "#material_id" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
            });
          } );
        </script>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <b>Select Asset to transcode</b>
        {{form.as_p}}
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The goal is to get it working with the default values, then i will change them to data in a model. Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by looking at the source code which the template produces.

I had to change:

```
$( "#material_id" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

to

```
$( "#id_material_id" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

This is due to `{{form.as_p}}` appending "id_" to the variable names in `form.py`.